# DataPackage.SetBitmap is not working in Windows phone 8.1 WinRT App

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am using following code to share image in my windows phone 8.1 App.

```
private async void MainPage_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();
        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await bitmap.RenderAsync(this);

        // 1. Get the pixels
        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

        // 2. Write the pixels to a InMemoryRandomAccessStream
        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);

        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96, 96,
            pixels);

        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        stream.Seek(0);

        // 3. Share it
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "test";
        args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "test";
        args.Request.Data.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));
        deferral.Complete();

    }
```

Above code shows **'Preparing content to share'** view but it doesn't show the list of apps to share the image.

However, everything works fine if I use **DataPackage.SetText**.

Couldn't figure out the problem.Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two links helped me in capturing screenshot.

[Taking Screenshot](https://techiepolitan.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/taking-a-screenshot-by-code-in-win-phone-8-1-rt-part-1/)

[Saving and Sharing Screenshot](https://techiepolitan.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/savingsharing-screenshot-in-win-phone-8-1-rt-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Save image to file, then attach file do DataPackage like this:

```
    args.Request.Data.SetStorageItems(new List<IStorageFile> { yourPngFile });
```